# Count points from View

Tags: sql-server, database

I got this View (this is sample data):

```
HomeTeam          HomeTeamScore        AwayTeamScore       AwayTeam
---------------------------------------------------------------
Middlesbrough         3                       1            Manchester United
Manchester City       1                       1            Liverpool
Liverpool             2                       0            Middlesbrough
Manchester United     3                       2            Manchester City
```

I count number of goals scored by home teams this way (similary I count number of goals scored by away teams):

```
SELECT HomeTeam, SUM (HomeTeamScore) AS CountGoals
FROM vW_Match   
GROUP BY HomeTeam ORDER BY CountGoals DESC
```

How Can I count points of teams? If result draws both teams get 1 point, if first team score more goals then away team, it get 3 points, and if away teams score more goals it get 3 points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try it

```
  ;WITH temps AS
  (SELECT HomeTeam AS Team, 
          case when HomeTeamScore = AwayTeamScore then 1 
               when HomeTeamScore > AwayTeamScore then 3
                 ELSE 0
          end AS Point
   FROM vW_Match   
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT AwayTeam AS Team, 
          case when HomeTeamScore = AwayTeamScore then 1 
               when AwayTeamScore  > HomeTeamScore  then 3
               ELSE 0
          end AS Point
   FROM vW_Match  
   )
  select  t.Team, sum(t.Point) as TotalPoint
  from temps t
  group by t.Team
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
SELECT team, sum(points) from (
    select   HomeTeam as team, 
    case 
    when HomeTeamScore > AwayTeamScore then 3
    when HomeTeamScore = AwayTeamScore then 1
    ELSE 0
    end as points
    FROM vW_Match   

    UNION ALL 

    select AwayTeam as team, 
    case 
    when HomeTeamScore > AwayTeamScore then 0
    when HomeTeamScore = AwayTeamScore then 1
    ELSE 3
    end as points 
    FROM vW_Match   
) t
GROUP BY team
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a CASE statement to compare results per team, you could get the respective points per game:

```
select HomeTeam, 
       HomeTeamScore,
       case when HomeTeamScore = AwayTeamScore then 1 
        when HomeTeamScore > AwayTeamScore then 3
        when HomeTeamScore < AwayTeamScore then 0
        end as HomeTeamPoints,
       AwayTeam,
       AwayTeamScore,
       case when AwayTeamScore = HomeTeamScore then 1 
        when AwayTeamScore > HomeTeamScore then 3
        when AwayTeamScore < HomeTeamScore then 0
        end as AwayTeamPoints
from vW_Match
```

This will give you results for both teams in different columns.